# In Java, is there difference to initializate and use an object as Base b = new Derived() and Derived e = new Derived()?

Tags: java, oop

If I have

```
    public class Base{  
        public void method(){
            System.out.println("I am base");
        } 
    }

    public class Derived extends Base{  
        public void method(){
            System.out.println("I am derived");
        }  
    }
```

is there a difference between

```
Base b = new Derived();
```

and

```
Derived d = new Derived();
```

? And, would

```
b.method();
d.method();
```

print the same?

Comment: They would print the same. However if `Derived` contained methods that didn't exist in `Base`, then you wouldn't be able to call them. i.e. if `Derived` had `otherMethod()`, you can't do `b.otherMethod()`.

Comment: @4castle, thank you. I suppose that is all the difference.

Comment: In many cases it's better to do `Base b = new Derived()` though, because it allows you to easily switch to another class that extends `Base`, and it's clearer in your code that you only plan on using the methods from `Base`. For example, most people prefer `Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>()` because it allows for a quick transition to `TreeMap` later down the line.